# add value to textarea per column using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap modal which contains a textarea element. I also have a dynamic table where you can add a column. My problem is, when I click the `note/comment` button icon, then input some text and when I click save, then all the `textarea`s inside the modal fill up.

This is some of my code

```
function save_modal(){
    data = {};
    $("#save").on("click", function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); // prevent de default action, which is to submit
        $('#Mymodal').modal('toggle'); //or  $('#IDModal').modal('hide');
        return false;
    });
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is that what you inputted should stay there in the `textarea` even if you're adding a new column.

**Please see the demo**

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/jdesparas/1pyhwb70/35/)**

Comment: Your modal keeps appearing every time I click save. Please check that code.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the single popup layout for all instances. You should clean up popup content (`.html('')`) after saving or always cloning (`.clone()`) popup layout before openning.

Comment: Ok it seems now you created separate  instance for each modal popup, but there are issue with saving data : you should unbind events before binding new ones like 
  $('.note').off("click"); .....   $("#save-"+num).off("click"); .... or does not bind it twice for old popups buttons.

Comment: But I would advice you use dictionary ({})  for storing data for each note  where property name  is index and value contains popup data instead creating new popup for each notes field. It allows to avoid cloning data and memory leak for really huge table. You could set data from dictionary  before popup openning. But with adding unbind events you code is working too if you do not plan to  use a lot of dynamic columns